# LVM snapshot at full disk installation

Tags: partitioning, lvm

Is it possible to take LVM snapshots of single whole disk installation under following circumstances?

```
root@talon1 ~ # lvs  
  LV     VG         Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   xubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 464.30g                                                    
  swap_1 xubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 980.00m                                                    
root@talon1 ~ # vgs
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  xubuntu-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- <465.26g    0 
root@talon1 ~ # fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 36D8E4F9-C29B-4F16-ABBB-1ED3F8168A1B

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 976771071 975720448 465.3G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root: 464.3 GiB, 498539167744 bytes, 973709312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-swap_1: 980 MiB, 1027604480 bytes, 2007040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

From [this](https://www.tecmint.com/take-snapshot-of-logical-volume-and-restore-in-lvm/) tutorial, it looks like I need a separate partition.

Is it also possible to create a small 15-16 GB partition on the fly and use that for snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

No unless you add another disk to the volume group.

Comment: I had a thought never done it before but you could use a ram disk if you have enough ram

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/925581)

Comment: I did answer his question his question was is it possible under these conditions and it a no.  He did not ask how go about resolving the issue.  I added that he would need to add additional storage.  If he changes the question, I'll change my answer.  I added my comment about ram disk because I don't know if it would work.

Comment: @nico Thanks. I appreciate that. RAM disk use is underrated.